# dimension reduction makes data non-linearly separable

Tags: svm, pca

I am working on a project to classify hearing disorders using SVM. I have collected real time data from the site (http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/audiology/) and initially decided to go for two classes to classify patients with normal ear and patients with any disorder. Varying the optimization parameter C from 0.1 to 10 I get one miss-classification between the two classes (C=10). 
However I wan to plot the data with the decision boundary but the data set has around 68 features so it is not possible to plot it. I used PCA to reduce to 2D and used svm on this data to see the results. But when I use PCA, the data no longer remains linearly separable and linear decision boundary cannot separate the 2D PCA data. So I want to know if there is a way to reduce dimension but to retain the nature of the data (nature as in separability using linear decision boundary). Can anyone please help me?

Thanks

Comment: Some data sets are simply not separable linearly in two (or even more) dimensions. So I don't think there's a general way for you solve this. Is it crucial for your application that you *plot* the data instead of simply computing the separating function with all 68 features?

Comment: well not crucial but I want to add some visual results to my results instead of showing some numbers of miss-classification. I tried LDA but the co-variance matrix has negative values and there is a warning that the matrix is close to singular. I don't think either of these will work. Thanks for the help

Comment: LDA will give a single dimension since you have 2 classes. You don't want that.